# This site can’t be reached https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt

Tags: php, facebook

This site can’t be reached

The webpage at `https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1&lwv=110` might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

```
ERR_FAILED
```

any way to resolve??

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same issue for the last couple of days.  A workaround is to edit the address line to just https://www.facebook.com and you (should) find you get access.